# Preload a background image for multiple iFrames?

Tags: iframe, preload

I have a few iFrames that all use a single background image. Whenever I click on a button to change the iFrame content, the browser seems to always load the image again, and there is a clear few-second delay. Is there any way to tell the browser to hold on to that file so there isn't that white flash and noticeable delay?

Comment: Iframe is basically a self independent page, it will act same as a new page on any browser tab. So instead of loading the new content by direct url use ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make iframes transparent, and give your image as background to the div where you load your iframes

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code for the table: [link](http://pastebin.com/iMmETMWA)